# How can I reload or recrate jstree with event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am trying to reload jstree treeview via calling func with click event. It does not reload with new data.

```
var MenuTree = function (user) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Permission.aspx/Menu",
        data: '{user: "' + user + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //$("#tree_menu").jstree('destroy');
            var menujson = JSON.parse(data.d);
            $('#tree_menu').jstree({
                'plugins': ["wholerow", "checkbox", "types"],
                "checkbox": {
                    "keep_selected_style": false,
                    "three_state": false
                },
                'core': {
                    "themes": {
                        "responsive": false
                    },
                    'data': menujson
                }
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('err')
        }
    });
```

When I first call MenuTree function it works and reload then when I am trying to call it again  it does not change.

When I use `$("#tree_menu").jstree('destroy');` before the `$('#tree_menu').jstree()`, it works except `deselect_node.jstree Event` and `select_node.jstree Event`.

How can I reload jstree with new data and events?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you can do,

```
.bind('any_event',function(e,data){

 $(tree).jstree('refresh);

});
```

This will reload your tree. Write the code in any event(jstree or jquery) and you are done!